# Should nested awaitable operations be awaited?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have been following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203179/should-i-await-readasstringasync-if-i-awaited-the-response-that-im-performing) and I understand the reasons behind the popular (albeit as-yet-unaccepted) answer by [Peter Duniho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3538012/peter-duniho).  Specifically, I am aware that *not* awaiting a subsequent long-running operation will block the UI thread:

> The second example does not yield during the asynchronous operation. Instead, by getting the value of the content.Result property, you force the current thread to wait until the asynchronous operation has completed.

I've even confirmed this, for my own benefit, like so:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value1 = await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            return "Hello";
        });

    //NOTE: this one is not awaited...
    var value2 = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            return value1.Substring(0, 3);
        });

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(value2.Result); //thus, UI freezes here after 5000 ms.
}
```

But now I'm wondering: do you need to `await` all "awaitable" operations nested within an outermost awaitable operation?  For example, I can do this:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value0 = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var value1 = new Func<Task<string>>(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(5000);
                return "hello";
            }).Invoke();

            var value2 = new Func<string, Task<string>>(async (string x) =>
                {
                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                    return x.Substring(0, 3);
                }).Invoke(value1.Result);

            return value2;
        });

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(value0); 
}
```

Or I can do this:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This time the lambda is async...
    var value0 = await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            //we're awaiting here now...
            var value1 = await new Func<Task<string>>(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(5000);
                return "hello";
            }).Invoke();

            //and we're awaiting here now, too...
            var value2 = await new Func<string, Task<string>>(async (string x) =>
                {
                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                    return x.Substring(0, 3);
                }).Invoke(value1);

            return value2;
        });

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(value0); 
}
```

And neither of them freeze the UI.  Which one is preferable?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if those all print the same thing, I believe that one is printing a Task object rather than its Result.

Comment: @BenVoigt -- No, bc in both cases the task is unwrapped since it's being awaited.

Comment: But one of those is wrapping a second Task.

Comment: @BenVoigt -- I see what you mean.  That's odd.  `value0` is a `string` in both cases, though, and it does print the same thing.\

Comment: Ahh, there are overloads for `Run<TResult>(Func<TResult>)` and `Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>>)`, the unwrap of the extra layer is performed there.

Comment: I'd love to know why someone down-voted my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The last one is preferable (although quite messy)

In TAP (Task-based Asynchronous Pattern) A task (and other awaitables) represent an asynchronous operation. You have basically 3 options of handling these tasks:

- Wait synchronously (`DoAsync().Result`, `DoAsync().Wait()`) - Blocks the calling thread until the task is completed. Makes your application more wasteful, less scalable, less responsive and susceptible to deadlocks.
- Wait asynchronously (`await DoAsync()`) - Doesn't block the calling thread. It basically registers the work after the `await` as a continuation to be executed after the awaited task completes.
- Don't wait at all (`DoAsync()`) - Doesn't block the calling thread, but also doesn't wait for the operation to complete. You are unaware of any exceptions thrown while `DoAsync` is processed

> Specifically, I am aware that not awaiting a subsequent long-running operation will block the UI thread

So, Not quite. If you don't wait at all, nothing will block but you can't know when or if the operation completed successfully. However, if you wait synchronously you will block the calling thread and you may have deadlocks if you're blocking the UI thread.

Conclusion: You should `await` your awaitables as long as that's possible (it isn't in `Main` for example). That includes "nested `async-await` operations".

About your specific example: `Task.Run` is used to offload CPU-bound work to a `ThreadPool` thread, which doesn't seem to be what you are trying to mimic. If we use `Task.Delay` to represent a truly asynchronous operation (usually I/O-bound) we can have "nested `async-await`" without `Task.Run`:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var response = await SendAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine(response); 
}

async Task<Response> SendAsync()
{
    await SendRequestAsync(new Request());
    var response = await RecieveResponseAsync();
    return response;
}

async Task SendRequestAsync(Request request)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000); // actual I/O operation
}

async Task<Response> RecieveResponseAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000); // actual I/O operation
    return null;
}
```

You can use anonymous delegates instead of methods, but it's uncomfortable when you need to define the types and invoke them yourself.

If you do need to offload that operation to a `ThreadPool` thread, just add `Task.Run`:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var response = await Task.Run(() => SendAsync());
    Debug.WriteLine(response); 
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm reading over your answer again, and I'm wondering if you could please clarify: are you saying that I *shouldn't* use nested awaits (which is what my third block of code is doing -- the one after "Or I can do this")?

Comment: @roryap I'm saying that if the operations are `async` then `await` them instead of blocking no matter where they are. About whether to use `Task.Run` zero, once or twice that depends on what you are *actually* trying to do (I'm assuming `Task.Delay` here is just a replacement).

Comment: @roryap If you have a long CPU intensive operation that you want to offload use `Task.Run`, otherwise simply invoke your `async` operations and `await` them.

Comment: The only reason I ask is because the code you included in your answer doesn't have any nested awaits (other than the one used with `Task.Delay`), which leads me to believe you were trying to say that that approach shouldn't be used at all.  Your code seems to be an example of how my *third* block of code could be refactored to achieve the same result, but I intentionally had it that way just as a throw-away example of nested awaits.  I'm just trying to wrap my head around it all.

Comment: @roryap There's nothing wrong with nested `async-await`s. I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @roryap take a look. I hope that clears everything up.

Comment: thank you for this answer; I'm a lot more experienced with this now but I come back to answers like this from time to time for a sanity check.  I wonder if you could answer a question that has nagged at me and for which I've never quite gotten a straight answer: how is it that `Task.Delay` is a truly-asynchronous operation?  Is it I/O bound somehow?  Which I/O?  Is there some hardware whose sole purpose is to count ticks, like a stopwatch?

Comment: @rory.ap It doesn't really matter what happens in hardware. Let's assume there is a thread in the runtime that is "sacrificed" to be a stopwatch. All it does is wakes up every 15 ms and synchronously sleeps for the rest. It is enough to "satisfy" many instances of different timers so that each `Task.Delay` call can be truly asynchronous by itself.

Comment: @rory.ap that BTW is somewhat how async IO is done in .NET. There's an I/O completion port with dedicated I/O completion port threads (waiting for I/O completions). But those few threads are enough to satisfy many asynchronous operations.

Comment: So what you're saying is that that thread is reserved (not available / in the thread pool for "normal" work) so the scalability concerns around borrowing thread pool threads for CPU-bound work do not come into play?

Comment: @rory.ap I'm talking about dedicated threads, not thread-pool threads. But I was making a hypothetical point, that even if there's no OS/Hardware capabilities you can get actual asynchrony for the application by sacrificing a single thread. The actual implementation does in fact utilize the OS's system clock (which I'm not sure enough about to comment)