# What's the cost of reading http content in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

I read through the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203179/should-i-await-readasstringasync-if-i-awaited-the-response-that-im-performing) that you should always `await` an asynchronous operation. That is not my concern, but instead why `await` the reading of http content in the first place. Content could be big but not neccessarily. I'm talking in the context of small content here.

Assume I know the content will be the following, why would I ever want to await the call? I'm asking this question with performance in mind.

{
    "regnr": "12345"
}

`var contentData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

vs

`var contentData = response.Content.ReadAsString();`

Comment: This stuff https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet allows you to benchmark

Comment: `await` will not provide improvements in performance - it provide improvements in availability.

Comment: Reading from a network stream is I/O-based, and thus an inherently asynchronous operation. Instead of asking "why would I ever want to await the call?", the correct question is "why would I ever want to block a thread?"

Comment: @StephenCleary I interpret your comment as: Reading the content from a network stream is always expensive, no matter how small the content itself is, so we rather not block the thread. Is this correct?

Comment: @JimAho: You could view it that way. I view it as "reading content is an asynchronous operation", so trying to make it synchronous - even though it is *possible* - is going against the very nature of the operation.

Comment: @StephenCleary Alright I see. I you'd like to compose it into an answer with relavant links i'll mark it as accepted for now.

Comment: @JimAho: It wasn't really an answer - just a comment that synchronous shouldn't be the default approach. The question is "which one is faster" (in this case), which I don't know.